# How can i get ID from Autocomplete DataSource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code for Autocomplete, It loads data and filter the result. But when items in the list selected or when submit button clicked i want navigate to details page as ...Product/Details/id. How can i get ID from the data source?

```
 <form id="Search" asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Product" method="post">
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                       .Name("Product")
                       .DataTextField("ProductName")                       
                       .Filter("contains")                  
                       .Template("#= ID# - #= ProductName #")                    
                       .DataSource(source =>
                        {
                        source
                            .Read(read =>
                            {
                            read.Action("Search", "Product")
                            .Data("onAdditionalData");
                            })
                        .ServerFiltering(false);
                       })
                )
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a combo box? The combo box supports key-value-pairs. Which seems to better suite your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(not tested):

```
$('#Product').data('kendoAutoComplete').on('change', function() {
    let selectedItem = this.dataItem();

    // Now you have all data on 'item' variable to use, e.g.:
    let id = selectedItem.id;
});
```

Place it between `<script></script>` tags after the code you've posted.